# Matching Specific Ad Based On Various Filters

Tags: php, elasticsearch, redis, logic, weblogic

I need a little help with someting I’d like to implement, but not sure how to do it.

I’m running eBay like classifieds site. There are a lot of filters on my site e.g. you can filter ads by price, by category, by city, by condition…
Let’s say we have this use case:

- User is able to filter ads on my site using filters
- Once he does it he can save those filters and subscribe to get push notification when someone submits an ad that matches those filters
- I save those filters in my database for that user
- For this example let’s say my site has around 100k active subscriptions.

The first step is obviously to attack a place in a code where ad is being saved to the database. I’m having a problem with how to know if that specific ad matches those filters.

I would need to go through 100k subscriptions and their filters to know which filter matches the ad that has been posted. It doesn’t sound too good for me, it could be 1M filters or more.

Can someone help me with that or at least point me to the right direction.

This is basic version.

Filters:

- country, county, city
- min price, max price
- condition (new,old…)
- ads with/without picture

User A subscribed to set of filters:

- England, London
- Min price: 200 €
- X
- X

User B subscribed to set of filters:

- England
- Max Price: 500€
- New
- X

User C subscribed to set of filters:

- Germany
- Min price: 200 €
- X
- With pictures

User X submitted ad with following data:

- City: London
- Price: 300 €
- Condition: New

In this case User A and User B need to get push notification because ad matches their filters.

Answer (score 0):

Very high-level view of what can be done.

**API:** Create an API **getFilteredAds**, passing in the request :

1. Contextual Information (user_id, etc)
2. Filter

**Filters:**

1. Save user filters on the backend
2. On clicking the filter UI can call the API 'getFilteredAds'

**Processing:**

1. getFilteredAds can get Data from Elastic Search based on the filters selected.
   (You can use any templating tool to define ES query template and generating the actual query based on filters data provided in the request)

Comment: Wouldn't that be too much? Going through all subscriptions plus querying elastic for each subscription?

Comment: Elastic Search is a distributed system, which is super fast for filtration, search, aggregation. Can you please explain a bit about what you meant by "Going through all subscription"? I am assuming you have an index containing ads data.

Comment: I have subscriptions saved in MySQL database. When person subscribes to set of filters I save it to the MySQL database so there can be thousands of rows